# Help finding a book from a summary

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I am trying to find the title of a book where siblings have two halves of this pyramid thingy, put them together, and get stuck in a pocket out of time with dinosaurs and a few thousand people who are stuck there too. I listened to the book a few years ago when I was 6-7 and it scared me a lot so my mom got rid of it. I now think it would be worth a read. Any ideas? I may have gotten a few bits of it wrong.

Comment: Sounds like [Dragon Tales](https://images.rapgenius.com/d56637e47f61205504012db5c45251fb.464x270x1.gif). But there aren't a few thousand people in it. So that's probably not it.

Comment: Was there an old lady who got stepped on?  Think  I might have read that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be [*Footprints of Thunder*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312854781) by James F. David?

The summary mentions time displacement, but no "pyramid thingy".

> When the boundaries between past and present dissolve, flooding the earth with dinosaurs and turning cities into primeval forests, an increasingly unstable American president searches desperately for a solution to the imminent apocalypse.

A quick dive into the Google Books excerpts shows that two of the main characters are Chris and Rosa, a pair of stepsiblings from a blended family.

[image: *Footprints of Thunder* cover]

I don't know if this is the book you read but I pretty sure it's the one I read, especially after seeing the alternate cover.

[image: *Footprints of Thunder* alternate cover]

Comment: This was It. Thanks you. I was six and barely remembered it.